# How do I remove the top and bottom bars on Google Play Books when I'm reading?

Tags: ebooks, google-play-books

The top and bottom bars are obtrusive and covers the top and bottom part of the text in the books I read. I tried tapping on the screen once but the bars would only flicker and not hide. Is there a way to force them hidden?

[image]

Comment: That is odd that they don't disappear. I just checked mine and the bars disappear when I tap somewhere in the text or when I swipe to the next page. They stay gone until I tap the page again.

Comment: Does swiping up do anything?

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: And what version of Play Books do you have?

Comment: I have the latest Play Books version and am on ST17i. ICS

Comment: I just tried sliding up, same result. The bars would just flicker.